# stacking validation messages

Tags: html, css, asp.net, popup

I have this below style to show asp.net validations as popup.

```
    .triangle-right.top::after
    {
        border-color: transparent #f00;
        border-width: 10px 0 0 10px;
        bottom: auto;
        left: 15px;
        top: -8px;
    }
    .triangle-right::after
    {
        border-color: #f00 transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 20px 0 0 20px;
        bottom: -20px;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        left: 50px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
    }
    .triangle-right.top
    {
        background: #f00 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    }
    .triangle-right
    {
        background: #f00 none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #fff;
        height: 28px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: 40px;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
</style>
```

Below is how I use this css.

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="FirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name is required" ForeColor="#FFFFFF"
                             CssClass="triangle-right top"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

This is how it displays.
[image]
This works well until I have only one message to display. I have certain cases where a control may not follow more than one validation. So all the error messages are popping up one over the other. Can anyone help me in solving this?

Comment: Guys, I am sill struck. Please help.

Comment: Atleast any alternate way to display validations as popups that do not overlap.